# Meaning of "See you at the A and P" in Speed-the-Plow by David Mamet

Tags: theater, david-mamet, speed-the-plow

In Mamet's Speed-the-Plow, what does Fox mean by "See you at A and P
"? Here:

> KAREN: I don't belong here.
>
> FOX: Well, I can help you out on that. You
> ever come on the lot again, I'm going to have you killed. Goodbye. **See
> you at the A and P**.
>
> KAREN: Goodbye.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Until they went bankrupt in 2015, A&P was a chain of supermarket stores, and in their heyday, they were a fairly large chain. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%26P).

The British equivalent of this line would thus likely be "See you at Tesco."

In a comment, Gareth Rees suggests that by this, Fox is implying that the only job Karen (who has just been fired) will be able to get is a cashier at the A&P. This seems like a very plausible interpretation to me.

Comment: Can you comment on the meaning of the line in the play? Fox has just fired his secretary Karen in a particularly brutal way after she tried to get Gould to pitch her movie concept. Does Fox mean that he expects to see her working as a cashier since (he thinks) she has no future in Hollywood?

Comment: @GarethRees: that's a quite likely interpretation, that I didn't think of.